# MYSQL complex GROUP BY and SUM query failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this convoluted query that is getting current inventory levels & converting the units to pounds, then looking at outstanding orders & converting the units to pounds, and finally display a summed amount needed of each ingredient for all outstanding orders.

The purpose is to list the ingredients with a inventory level and then an amount needed to fulfill all outstanding order. If the baker does not have enough flour then he can see this and look into sourcing more before he begins baking for the day.

The problem is then when I run this query it is skipping the first row in the group function. When I run it without grouping it gets all the rows correct, but when i run it with a SUM and GROUP BY it skips the first row so it under calculates that items amount needed value. Any tips? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    inventory.id, 
    inventory.title, 
    products.weight, 
    products.id AS product_id, 
    (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS quantity_to_be_baked,
    (SELECT @inventory_pounds:=
        CASE inventory.units
            WHEN  'kilograms'
            THEN 2.20462 * inventory.quantity
            WHEN  'pounds'
            THEN 1 * inventory.quantity
            WHEN  'ounces'
            THEN 0.0625 * inventory.quantity
            WHEN  'grams'
            THEN 0.00220462 * inventory.quantity
        END ) as inventory_pounds,
    (SELECT @dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds:=
        CASE dough_recipes.units
            WHEN 'kilograms'
            THEN 2.20462 * dough_recipes.amount
            WHEN 'pounds'
            THEN 1 * dough_recipes.amount
            WHEN 'ounces'
            THEN 0.0625 * dough_recipes.amount
            WHEN 'grams'
            THEN 0.00220462 * dough_recipes.amount
        END ) AS dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds, 
    (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS num_loaves_needed,
    ( SELECT @dough_recipe_yield_pounds:=
        CASE doughs.units
            WHEN 'kilograms'
            THEN 2.20462 * doughs.yield
            WHEN 'pounds'
            THEN 1 * doughs.yield
            WHEN 'ounces'
            THEN 0.0625 * doughs.yield
            WHEN 'grams'
            THEN 0.00220462 * doughs.yield
        END ) AS dough_recipe_yield_pounds,
    (SELECT SUM( @dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds / @dough_recipe_yield_pounds * weight * (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked))) as amount_needed_for_orders
    FROM inventory
    LEFT JOIN dough_recipes ON inventory.id = dough_recipes.inventory_id
    LEFT JOIN products ON dough_recipes.dough_id = products.dough_id
    LEFT JOIN orders_items ON products.id = orders_items.product_id AND (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) > 0
    LEFT JOIN doughs ON doughs.id = products.dough_id
    GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I'm surprised mysql is not complaining about the ambiguity of the `id` in the `GROUP BY` clause - which table `id` is it?

Comment: Please use paragraph breaks.

Comment: there is only one 'id'

Comment: Thanks for adding the paragraph breaks. I am using the query without group by and sum and formatting the results in php.

Comment: any chance you could make a fiddle @ sqlfiddle.com while everyone is taking a look?

Comment: I'd consider radically altering the design, to only store metric units, and do all the conversion stuff client side - in the user's javascript. That way they can choose whatever units they like.

Comment: Yah I originally had all units stored as grams, but when you add 999,999 pounds of say water when converted to grams it becomes 4.53592e8. I wanted to make it flexible enough to handle any size inventory in any unit. I like to make things difficult for myself ;)

Comment: @jacky Chengm, I never knew about SQL fiddle that is pretty cool! I cannot set one up until Tuesday.

Comment: @user2094495 That's just a formatting problem. No biggie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group by` does not skip rows or anything. Your query structure seems just wrong. Have a try with this:

```
SELECT SUM(dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds / dough_recipe_yield_pounds * weight * (quantity - quantity_baked))) as amount_needed_for_orders
FROM (
    SELECT 
    inventory.id, 
    inventory.title, 
    products.weight, 
    products.id AS product_id, 
    orders_items.quantity,
    orders_items.quantity_baked,
    (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS quantity_to_be_baked,
        CASE inventory.units
            WHEN  'kilograms'
            THEN 2.20462 * inventory.quantity
            WHEN  'pounds'
            THEN 1 * inventory.quantity
            WHEN  'ounces'
            THEN 0.0625 * inventory.quantity
            WHEN  'grams'
            THEN 0.00220462 * inventory.quantity
        END as inventory_pounds,
        CASE dough_recipes.units
            WHEN 'kilograms'
            THEN 2.20462 * dough_recipes.amount
            WHEN 'pounds'
            THEN 1 * dough_recipes.amount
            WHEN 'ounces'
            THEN 0.0625 * dough_recipes.amount
            WHEN 'grams'
            THEN 0.00220462 * dough_recipes.amount
        END  AS dough_recipe_ingredient_pounds, 
    (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS num_loaves_needed,
        CASE doughs.units
            WHEN 'kilograms'
            THEN 2.20462 * doughs.yield
            WHEN 'pounds'
            THEN 1 * doughs.yield
            WHEN 'ounces'
            THEN 0.0625 * doughs.yield
            WHEN 'grams'
            THEN 0.00220462 * doughs.yield
        END AS dough_recipe_yield_pounds
    FROM inventory
    LEFT JOIN dough_recipes ON inventory.id = dough_recipes.inventory_id
    LEFT JOIN products ON dough_recipes.dough_id = products.dough_id
    LEFT JOIN orders_items ON products.id = orders_items.product_id AND (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) > 0
    LEFT JOIN doughs ON doughs.id = products.dough_id
) sq
GROUP BY id
```

If this is really the right query for what you're looking for, we can't tell without sample data and desired result. Above query is just a guess based on your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I'll make sure to test it out when I get back to my machine.

Comment: This query works! Thanks a lot, there was one extra ) in the first grouping but other than that it was perfect. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

i'll give it a blind shot as I can't test it without a fiddle. ( I actually can but I am too dam lazy)

Sometimes a badly structured `group by` will hide data from you, try the following and see if it helps.

```
GROUP BY inventory.id, products.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll make sure to test it out when I get back to my machine.